# Inequality for exponential sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, central-limit-theorem, exponential-sum

I'm currently trying to figure out the following inequality. It looks like an inequality for the exponential sum, but I can't verify it or find a source explaining it any further. Most likely it has to do with the remainder I guess...
$$|E[\exp(itX_{n,k})|F_{n,k-1}]-1-\frac{1}{2}t^2E[X_{n,k}^2|F_{n,k-1}]|\\
\leq \frac{1}{6}|t|^3E[|X_{n,k}|^3\mathrm{1}_{|X_{n,k}|\leq \epsilon}\big{|}F_{n,k-1}]+t^2E[X_{n,k}^21_{X_{n,k}>\epsilon}|F_{n,k-1}]$$

Where $E[X_{n,k}|F_{n,k-1}]=0$ for all $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Especially this is taken from 
Dvoretzky, 1972, ASYMPTOTIC NORMALITY FOR SUMS OF DEPENDENT RANDOM VARIABLES
and can be found in the proof of theorem 2.1 equality (4.4). Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like $e^{itX_{n,k}}$ has been expanded into a power series in $t$, and the error term after $t^2$ term is used.

Comment: Yeah but how does one obtain the Indicators?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "indicators".

Comment: I meant the conditioning of both expectations on ${|X_{n,k}|\leq \epsilon} $ respectively ${|X_{n,k}| > \epsilon}$

Answer (score 0):

Somebody on MO just pointed out to me that the inequality, especially the first term in the second line comes from the remainder in integral form of the corresponding Taylor series.